# Deriving Burgers' equation from physical situation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

The Burgers' equation is given by
$$u_t+uu_x=0.$$ I am trying to understand what this equation means. How it represents the relation between change of $u$ with respect to $t$ and change of $u$ with respect to $x$? How is this equation derived? I have tried to find on Google to get the exact meaning of this equation but I am not getting any. Any explanation would be helpful.

Comment: The guy's name was [Burgers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_Burgers), not Burger. If you write the equation as $u_t + (\tfrac12 u^2)_x = 0$, you see that it's a conservation law with flux $\tfrac12 u^2$.

Comment: Can you provide some resources to understand this conservation laws? I am a pure math student and wanted to study about weak solutions. In the introduction of the course the Burgers' equation is given as a motivation but they have provided mathematical analysis to show that the solution is not even a function. So I wanted to learn more about this equation

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're looking for, but Whitham's *Linear and Nonlinear Waves* is perhaps a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivation of Burgers' equation is carried out in the book *Theory of Nonlinear Acoustics in Fluids* by [Enflo & Hedberg](https://doi.org/10.1007/0-306-48419-6) (Kluwer Academic Publishers, 2002), but other references might deal with it as well (see for instance the books *Nonlinear Acoustics* by Hamilton & Blackstock or *Nonlinear Wave Processes in Acoustics* by [Naugolnykh & Ostrovsky](http://www.cambridge.org/052139080X), 1998). Usually, a slow variation assumption is made, that amounts to a change of variables combined with an asymptotic expansion. Then, the Burgers equation follows from keeping only leading-order terms (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3115258/418542)) -- more heuristic approaches are also possible, see [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/524520/186691).